# Obtaining Vcpkg paths within a CMake script

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

Is there a simple way to find either the root, or the "installed" subdirectory of Microsoft's Vcpkg, from within a CMake build script? Let's assume the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` has already been set to the standard vcpkg.cmake file.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to set an environment variable to tell CMake where to find the toolchain file.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer: Call cmake with `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%VCPKG_ROOT%\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`