# What's the idiomatic way to configure a CMake project with `vcpkg`?

Tags: cmake, build, vcpkg

I'm modifying a project which uses CMake to include a library which is managed by `vcpkg`.

It looks like in order for `vcpkg`'s packages to be found, `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` has to be defined... somewhere.

I'm confused because everything suggests that the value of `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` should contain the install location of `vcpkg` on the user's system, but I don't know how to reliably obtain that or get that information into the build system of the project. It certainly seems untenable to require each user to modify their copy of the project CMake files to point to their chosen install location. Requiring the developer / build system to set an env variable also seems pretty fragile and is not very well encapsulated (I'd hope that setup + build could be a single command).

I am pretty new to CMake and completely new to `vcpkg`. What is the idiomatic way to configure a project to use `vcpkg`?

Comment: "What is the idiomatic way to configure a project to use vcpkg?" - Idiomatic way is to pass `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` as a parameter to `cmake`: `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg/toolchain/file <other arguments>`. Yes, this requires a user to know a path to vcpkg installation on his/her machine. But this is just how things work.

Comment: To use vcpkg without any manual configuration from the user, I use it as a submodule in my projects : https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg#vcpkg-as-a-submodule

Comment: Possible answer: `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%VCPKG_ROOT%\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52077250/5067822

Answer (score 3):

Possible answer: `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%VCPKG_ROOT%\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`